# JqueryInAction Book Example Uses Local Variable Instead of this

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, closures

I am new to Jquery and reading 'JQueryInAction' book. 
I came across this example from this book:

```
$(function(){
    $('*').each(function(){
        var current = this;
        this. onclick = function(event) {
            if (!event) event = window.event;
            var target = (event.target) ? event.target : event.srcElement;
            say('For ' + current.tagName + '#'+ current.id +
                ' target is ' + target.id);
        }
    });
});
```

Here I really don't understand use of local variable `current` instead of `this` at line no 3.

Note: I know JavaScript and I understand `closures` and how `this` is not available inside `closure` But that is not the case here, `this` is available inside the event handler.
What is the significance of `current` here.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to the introduction of ES6 arrow functions all functions had their own `this` the value of which is determined by how the function is called.

Here the event handler has its own `this` but also needs access to the `this` of its enclosing lexical context, but it clearly can't use `this` for both. To resolve the problem the value of `this` from the outer function is saved to a new variable so it can be used in the handler without issue.

ES6 [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) do not have their own `this` or `arguments`; the `this` value of the enclosing execution context is used instead.

Your code could be rewritten as:

```
$('*').each(function() {
  this.onclick = (event) => {
    if (!event) event = window.event;
    var target = (event.target) ? event.target : event.srcElement;
    say('For ' + this.tagName + '#'+ this.id + ' target is ' + target.id);
  }
});
```

Comment: Isn't this inside is the same this in outer envirnment, as the event handler is called on the this of the outer lexical envirnment?